# ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have requirement like this- my activity contains some textviews at the top then the expandable list view in the middle and a button at the bottom. my problem is when i clicked on
expandable list view the expanded list get accommodated  in the space between button and expandable list view.

I wanted expandable list view to get expanded full and button should move downward according to the contains of the expandable list view. And i have used scrollview as a main layout.
thank you

Comment: Post your xml layout. Probably you have to use height=wrap_layout Puting a listview inside a scrollview is not advised as the list alread knows how to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a LinearLayout with android:layout_weight attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ScrollView as the main layout, use a LinearLayout but without the Button. For eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ExpandableListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Now in code, add the Button as the footerView of the ExpandableListView as :

```
final ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
Button btn = new Button(this);
elv.addFooterView(btn);
```

The button will always be present at the end of the ExpandableListView using this. Just as you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your expandable Listview and your button in a relative layout, and set align below is your button, It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Custom ExpandableListView Tutorial**

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.